# Curious sighting regarding Up votes on comments in the election

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, comments, voting

So, if you review the election link:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1

Scroll down to comments on @Ryan's nomination....

[image]

How is it that the comment from @bjb568 has an up vote???

I **don't even have the *option* of up voting comments** in the election link.

So, how is this possible?

Comment: *Have I been summoned?* :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug that is occasionally exploited for fun by a very small number of users who like pushing the boundaries of SE software. Reported by Ilmari Karonen in [Can *too* upvote comments under an election nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245124):

> Basically, it's yet another back-end validation issue: while the upvote button is missing from the page HTML, the SE back-end is still happy to accept and display upvotes for election comments, so all you need to do to restore the missing functionality is to edit the page HTML in your browser's dev tools and paste in the code for the upvote button from some other page.

Answer (score 3):

[This has now been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252916/165581).

> Voting for comments has been disabled during the nomination phase for now. We want to make sure that we are at consistent when it comes to elections.